# Why is specify the name of a subquery in wild card resulting in different query result in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

Given the following table definition

```
-- Table: public.my_table

-- DROP TABLE public.my_table;

CREATE TABLE public.my_table
(
    row_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('my_table_id_seq'::regclass),
    user_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    item_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    my_timestamp timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT my_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (row_id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.my_table
    OWNER to my_db;
```

I am trying to find that how many number of items have more than one rows.

Here is my query.

```
select count(k.*) from (select count(item_id), item_id
from my_table as t
group by item_id
having count(item_id) > 1) as k
```

which returns

```
count1 for item1
count2 for item2
....
```

which is not what I want

Here is another query

```
select count(*) from (select count(item_id), item_id
from my_table as t
group by item_id
having count(item_id) > 1) as k
```

which returns exactly what I want

```
count
```

I am curious on why is there a discrepancy, I thought the 2 queries are the same, one is count the result row of k explicitly and one is implicit.

Can someone guide me through the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the behavior of `COUNT(record)` is different between versions:

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    row_id bigint NOT NULL ,
    user_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    item_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    my_timestamp timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT my_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (row_id)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(1,'a','a'),(2,'a','a'),(3,'b','b'),(4,'b','b')
,(5,'c','c'),(6,'c','c'),(7,'c','c'),(8,'d','d'),(9,'d','d');
```

Query:

```
select COUNT(k.*)
from (select count(item_id), item_id
      from my_table as t
      group by item_id
      having count(item_id) > 1) as k

-- PostgreSQL 10
-- count
--2
--2
--2
--3

-- PostgreSQL 11
-- count
-- 4
```

[DBFiddle Demo PostgreSQL 10.4](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=000a1ab1b6cbb154fc78b2a317479d32)

[DBFiddle Demo PostgreSQL 11beta2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=000a1ab1b6cbb154fc78b2a317479d32)

---

Checking execution plans `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)`:

[image][image]

<sub>Plans generated using http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans</sub>

As we can see in first example there is no second aggregation at all.

---

I would use simple `COUNT(*)` or replace `COUNT(k.*)` with `COUNT(ROW(k.*))`:

```
select COUNT(*), COUNT(ROW(k.*)) 
from (select count(item_id), item_id
      from my_table as t
      group by item_id
      having count(item_id) > 1) as k;

-- count count
-- 4     4
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5fd2be5d5f3f476cd717f1d35dbc0e87)**

Comment: The result in Postgres 10 is a bug I would say

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, it looks like every version before PostgreSQL 11 return incorrect results.